# Why does Kant say that 'something possible is actual' is the same as 'much is possible that is not actual'?

Tags: logic, kant

Between B283-284 of the Critique of Pure Reason Kant says that 'something possible is actual' "seems to mean as much as" saying 'much is possible that is not actual'. It's been a while since I've done my square of opposition work, can someone explain to me what he means?

Comment: IIRC, he actually objects to the equivalence. He notes that the "ordinary language" of the claims lines up (pragmatically) (and he must be speaking of German, I expect) but that more strictly, the two claims are quite different. His prising them apart is part and parcel of his moderately-to-strongly skeptical epistemology of modality.

Comment: He derived "some P is A" from "all A is P" by the so-called [converse by limitation](https://academic.csuohio.edu/polen/LC9_Help/4/immediate.htm). Under the colloquial meaning of "some" this seems to imply that "some P is not A", but this inference is logically invalid. "Some P is A" includes "all P is A", i.e. A and P could coincide. He then says that "*adding  to  the  possible  to  constitute the  actual*" he does not allow, and  what is not actual is not "*in  all  respects  possible*" either. Thus, his "actual"="possible" are not what we mean by them today.

Comment: These may not be logically equivalent but could be said to be self-implied in everyday conversations, such as "*Some students got high scores for this difficult exam*" could imply "*Most other students didn't get high scores for the said exam*"...